# unable to add picture from url to my runtime created textView in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two activities in my android app in opening activity I'm pasting a url into edit text and on clicking fetch button it extracts the description and title of given URL and opens new activity with URL, title and description added to edittext of 2nd activity and on clicking button I want to create a new textview with URL info with related picture and add it to layout like messages are adds in WhatsApp app on clicking send button. I'm successful in creating textview with url info but the picture is not coming. here is my 2nd activity code..... 
 note: url of the image I've given is not runtime generated I gave a constant image src for debugging purpose.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wall);
    initialize();
    Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
    baseurl = gotBasket.getString("url");
    title = gotBasket.getString("title");
    description = gotBasket.getString("des");
    imgsrc = gotBasket.getString("img");
    info = baseurl +"\n" + title + "\n" + description;
    content.setText(info);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public void onClick(View v){
    String cntnt = content.getText().toString();
    wall.addView(createNewTextView(cntnt));
    content.setText("");
    scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    textView = new TextView(this);
    int id = View.generateViewId();
    textView.setId(id);
    lparams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    lparams.setMargins(200,10,10,0);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setText(text);
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    gd.setStroke(2, Color.BLACK);
    gd.setCornerRadius(20.0f);
    textView.setBackground(gd);
    textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    new FetchImageAsyncTask().execute();
    return textView;
}

private void initialize() {
    wall = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wall);
    content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.content);
    post = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.post);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    post.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
public class FetchImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Drawable d;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            //imgsrc = "//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Aishwarya_Rai_Cannes_2017.jpg/220px-Aishwarya_Rai_Cannes_2017.jpg";
            URL aURL = new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Aishwarya_Rai_Cannes_2017.jpg/220px-Aishwarya_Rai_Cannes_2017.jpg");
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();

            d =new BitmapDrawable(bm);
            //image = Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream)new URL("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aishwarya_Rai_Cannes_2017.jpg").getContent(), "src");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remote Image Exception", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        textView.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to pass your image in `byte[]` instead of passing in string from one activity to another.

Comment: do i need to use URLConnection in my opening activity's asynktask where i'am using jsoup.connect to fetch title and description or there is a function to get bitmap of image in jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) you can set textview drawable:
add this dependency in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Glide.with(this)
        .load(((FixturesListObject) object).getHomeIcon())
        .asBitmap()
        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100,100) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                        txtView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, new BitmapDrawable(left.getResources(),resource), null, null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: where i supposed to use this code in the body of onpostexecute function of asynktask or anywhere else?